# Encouraging Open Source Project Programmers to Be Active Without Sacrificing Code Quality

Tags: open-source, project-management

I have an open source project which I had been actively developing

[JStock - Free Stock Market Software](http://jstock.sourceforge.net)

From programming side point of view, most of the time, is solo work.

This worry me. As for long term growth of JStock, is is not healthy.

Although I do have a few programmers as team members, they are not actively involve. Most of them are just one or two times code contributors. After that, I received no news from them.

The main reason I think they are not active, is due to some strict rule which I had imposed :

> No commit write being given. All the
>   changes must be submitted as patches,
>   and reviewed by me

See, even myself also doesn't like this strict rule.

I had removed this rule once, and let the programmers have the freedom to commit the code as they like. As a result, just after a few days, I found the code being messed up (Being messed up mean, cann't even compile). I have no way, but quickly stop the commit access, and recover the source code manually.

I feel that :

1. Too much rules, bad for programmers. They will not contribute.
2. No rule, bad for end users. They will be using product built from messed code.

I know in current situation is totally unhealthy for JStock. May I know how do you all encourage the programmers to contribute code, at the same time maintain certain degree of code quality?

Currently, JStock do have

1. [Feature Tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=202896&atid=983421) and [Bug Tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=202896&atid=983418). They are actively being used.
2. [Forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jstock/forums/forum/723856) for developers.
3. [CVS](http://jstock.cvs.sourceforge.net/jstock/)

Is Developer Guide PDF file is something must have, in order to let newly joint developer to understand the code? Or I shall let developers explore the 50,000 lines of code by their own?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds to me like your developers may not be very committed to your project.

Comment: I would say, the main obstacle is due to my policy. It will lower down the spirit of programmers. I need to get them excited, to let them commit the code by themselves :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about community management, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. Your project looks pretty nice. Also the website is quite attractive (If it was mine, I would get rid of the Google Ads but that's down to personal taste).

Maybe you should create a specific page section "developers", serving news, specific info, CVS snapshots... At the moment, it's very hard for an interested developer to find out more about how the project is developed, who is leading it, coding conventions... The blog is a start but it's not actively *inviting* participation. One would have to contact you and maybe that's already too much of a commitment for some before knowing more details about the project.

Do you have a feature wish list?

Can people put up bounties for desired new features? It's stuff for a longer discussion whether that is good and healthy to do in an Open Source project, but just as an idea. I mean, when I need to keep track of the stock market, I'm likely to have some extra dough lying around, don't I?

Comment: Ya. I get what you means. My initial plan is the has less menu items at my website, so that end users can really find what they want (Downloads). Having an extra menu item called "Development", will certainly confuse end users who are not computer literature. I treat end users as King. I certainly sure those who like to have code contribute are computer geek, and know where to look for ;) But I also get your point "...too much of a commitment for some before knowing more details about the project." Will think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Move from CVS to a distributed source control system (e.g. git, mercurial). That way anyone who wants can hack at the code, with proper source control, but commits to your code line have to be pushed to you explicitly.

Comment: Ya. SourceForge provides ubversion, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar, CVS. My only experience is with CVS. I shall test the rest out to see whether they fit my need (Branch/ Trunk permission)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should work with branches.

I'm not an expert on the field but I used it once and it worked well. We used [launchpad](http://launchpad.net/) to host our project and [bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) for source control. (which is nicely integrated in launchpad)

Anyone can mess up with the code in their own branch, and you can apply some control when you're merging a branch back in the main branch. This way developers have more freedom, without putting in danger the project.

Comment: So far as I know, sourceforge doesn't have branch/trunk permission management. Doesn't launchpad have it?

Comment: Yes, as far as I remember, branches have a owner, which can be a developer or a team. And only the owner (members of the team if it's a team) can commit to the branch. 
Branches can also have a reviewer, which is in charge of reviewing proposals and merging into the branch.
In your case, you could be the only owner and reviewer of the main branch, and let people do their stuff in theirs.
One last information : branches have an owner, a project, a name, a status (dev/mature/...), and may be attached to blueprints or bugs.

Comment: Argh. That is the feature which I really wish to have. SourceForge is providing Bazaar. Perhaps I shall just experiment it out.

Answer (score 0):

Within web2project - http://web2project.net/ - we use Sourceforge's Subversion for the primary/official code, but I've just launched us on Github for the unofficial one - http://github.com/caseysoftware/web2project

So far it's serving as a way for both a) core contributors to share unfinished pieces and b) community members to share patches without compromising the integrity of the core repository. As seen in our 'network', I've already applied one patch from a contributor and even created a branch based on what another community member has shared.

Of course, *NOTHING* goes into the master (and gets merged to trunk) without undergoing the same code review we do for everything else. Further, we have 200+ unit tests that are run regularly (continuous integration is next) and we're also working on contribution guidelines with the hope that people will filter out the worst stuff before we even see it.

Comment: Isn't having two code repository hosting at two different places, will confuse the developers on which code repository they shall work on?

Comment: No, because synchronizing is simple:
git->svn: git svn dcommit 
svn->git: git svn rebase